# Select between dates and with initial values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to make a graph from a log. The log entries are not in regular intervals.

I would like to select rows between dates along with what the values were immediately before the start date (that is, from whenever the immediatly preceeding log was entered).

So, let's say:

table `Foo` has `id` and `value` columns,

table `Bar` has `id`, `foo_id`, and `value` columns, and

table `BarLog` has `id`, `foo_id`, `bar_id`, `bar_value` and `timestamp`.

So there can be many Bars for one Foo.

I need all rows from BarLog for all Bars given some `foo_id` between, say,  `07/01/2012` and `07/31/2012` and the value (row) for each Bar as it was on `07/01/2012`.

Hope that made sense, if not, I'll try to clarify.

---

EDIT (above left for context):

Let's simplify this down another step. If I have  a table with two foreign keys, `fk_a` and `fk_b`, and a `timestamp`, how can I get the most recent rows with a given `fk_a` and a distict `fk_b`.

As suggested, here's an example.

```
+----+------+------+-------------+
| id | fk_a | fk_b |  timestamp  |
+----+------+------+-------------+
| 1  | 1    | 1    | 01-JUL-2012 |
| 2  | 2    | 2    | 02-JUL-2012 |
| 3  | 1    | 1    | 04-JUL-2012 |
| 4  | 2    | 2    | 05-JUL-2012 |
| 5  | 1    | 3    | 07-JUL-2012 |
+----+------+------+-------------+
```

Given a `fk_a` of 1, I would want rows 3 and 5. So looking only at rows 1, 3, and 5 (those with `fk_a` of 1), get the most recent of each `fk_b` (where row 3 is more recent than row 1 for `fk_b=1`).

Thanks again.

Comment: [How do _you_](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) think you should be doing this?

Comment: You should post some sample data and the result you want.

Comment: Ben, obviously, I don't know, I can't do a ORDER BY and TOP/LIMIT because I don't know how many, my only solution is iterating with TOP 1, but this means multiple queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql) which had what I was looking for. Basically just joining with a grouped select. So the answer for my edit would be something like

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable a
JOIN (
    SELECT fk_b, MAX(timestamp) as latest
    FROM SomeTable
    GROUP BY fk_b
) b
ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.fk_a = @someIdA
```

Which would return the latest of each distinct `fk_b` with a specified `fk_a`

The original question would just be a union of this with a simple get between dates

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
        SELECT bl.bar_value, timestamp
  FROM foo f, bar b, barlog bl
 WHERE     f.id = b.id
       AND b.foo_id = bl.foo_id
       AND timestamp BETWEEN '01-JUL-2012' AND '31-JUL-2012'
       AND b.foo_id = :enter_value_here
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Use the :enter_value_here to add the foo_id you need the data for...

What plotting tool are you using? You can take the data-set and push it into excel for plotting..in any case, hopefully the query above can get you closer to what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, but this is only half the answer, it's the values from immediately before the start date that I'm having issues with. And I'm using ASP.NET's built in charting framework.

Answer (score 0):

For a dense set, create a date table and run the following query:

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime

SET @StartDate = '2012-01-01'

SELECT f.ID as foo_id, b.bar_id, f.Value, GetDate() as DateStamp
FROM Foo f
inner join Bar b on f.id = b.foo_id
WHERE /*enter criteria for bar selection*/
UNION ALL
SELECT f.ID as foo_id, b.bar_id, f.Value, GetDate() as DateStamp
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(bl.timestamp) as bl_timestamp, bl.bar_id as bar_id
    FROM Dates d 
    INNER JOIN BarLog bl on bl.timestamp < d.Date
    WHERE /*enter criteria for bar selection*/
    GROUP BY bl.bar_id
) as pi
INNER JOIN BarLog bl on pi.bar_id = bl.bar_id and bl.timestamp = pi.bl_timestamp
WHERE d.Day_Of_Month = 1 and d.Date between @StartDate and getDate()
  AND /*enter criteria for bar selection*/
```

The date table can be something like http://it.toolbox.com/wiki/index.php/Create_a_Time_Dimension_/_Date_Table or could be created temporarily each query by:

```
CREATE TABLE #Dates ([Date] datetime, Day_Of_Month int)

DECLARE @cDate datetime
SET @cDate = @StartDate

WHILE @cDate < getdate()
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #Dates (Date, Day_Of_Month)
    SELECT @cDate, Datepart(d, @cdate)

    SET @cDate = DATEADD(m, 1 + DATEDIFF(m, 0, @cdate), 0)
END
```

with a `DROP TABLE #Dates` sitting after the select.

This query will return:

Foo_ID, Bar_ID, Value at datestamp, Datestamp

with the datestamps incrementing by 1 month at a time.